# Concatenating newline after ternary expression (Perl 5)

Tags: concatenation, ternary-operator, fizzbuzz, perl

I just wrote a simple fizzbuzz program in Perl:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
for $a (1..100) {
  print ($a%15 ? ($a%3 ? ($a%5 ? $a : "buzz") : "fizz") : "fizzbuzz") . $/;
}
```

It sort of works, but for some reason I'm not getting any line breaks in the output:

```
12fizz4buzzfizz78fizzbuzz11fizz1314fizzbuzz1617fizz19buzzfizz2223fizzbuzz26...
```

I know this can be fixed by adding `print $/;` as a separate statement at the end of the loop, but I can't figure out why this should be necessary.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> What am I doing wrong?

You're effectively doing `print ("foo") .$/` which concatenates `print` return value and `$/`.

Using `warnings` would give you `Useless use of concatenation (.) or string in void context`

Try to enclose everything with `()`

```
print (($a%15 ? ($a%3 ? ($a%5 ? $a : "buzz") : "fizz") : "fizzbuzz") . $/);
```

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks! (I'll try to remember to enable warnings next time.)

Answer (score 1):

The following statement

```
print ($a%15 ? ($a%3 ? ($a%5 ? $a : "buzz") : "fizz") : "fizzbuzz") . $/;
```

equals (more or less)

```
my $t = print ($a%15 ? ($a%3 ? ($a%5 ? $a : "buzz") : "fizz") : "fizzbuzz");
$t . $/;
```

Now I believe you can see the problem.